# How to use the .env file in the remote repo only when GitHub workflow runs

Tags: github, github-actions

I have GitHub repos for my backend and frontend project and I'm deploying them to AWS EC2 using GitHub Actions.

I know the frontend deployment needs the `.env` file in the build phase for frontend, but I did not push it to the GitHub repo because of sensitive information. I know I can use GitHub secrets for the environment variables but I don't want to use this approach because of having to manually add new secrets.

How can I set things up such that whenever I update the `.env` file locally, it automatically gets added to GitHub secrets. Or how can I push the `.env` file such that it is only available for use when the workflow is running?